# How to install Eclipse Web Tools on Eclipse Classic?

Tags: plugins, html, eclipse, web-development

I'm using eclipse 3.5.2 classic, and I'd like to install [Eclipse Web Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), but I can't find a url for which to install it.. can anyone find that? or does it not exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the link you posted, under the "Downloads" section (see screenshot below) there is a link to the update site ( http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates).  From the "Help" menu in Eclipse, select "Install New Software" and then click the "Add" button to add a new update site.  You can now select the site in the drop down and install the Web Tools.

Here is a screenshot of the website, as I see it. The link is circled.

[image: Webtools Website]

Answer (score 3):

You can either download the zip file [here](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.2.0/R-3.2.0-20100615235519/) and manually install it or use Eclipse's "Install new Software" and add the update site (http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates)

Comment: where did you find [this link](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates)?

Answer (score 3):

You can Install it from within Eclipse:
 Go to Help-->Install New Software
 Choose at "work with:" all available sites
 Enter web on the search and install web tools...

(and after that you have javascript etc. on eclipse)